# Image Slideshow Stops Displaying after the Final Image

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a Bootstrap JS Carousel which displays a number of images I have stored in the project folder.

The filepath of each image is retrieved from an SQL Server database, and the image is displayed in a carousel.

The images are being displayed, but my problem is that when it reaches the final image, rather than starting the slideshow again (at the first image), nothing else is displayed.

Does anyone know how I can get the first image to display after the final iamge? Like in a loop.

Below is my ASPX:

```
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Rgallary" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="item <%# (Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "") %>">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgId" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Company_Logo_Path", "~/Company_Logo/{0}") %>' />
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Local Companies
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindslide();
    }
    public void bindslide()
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        string connectionStringR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
            "ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ImagesTable", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Rgallary.DataSource = ds;
        Rgallary.DataBind();
        conn.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Usually a jQuery slideshow player has a `loop` setting somewhere. Check it's documentation.

Comment: @VDWWD Hi, It's the  Bootstrap JS Carousel, so I'll have a look at the documentation and see. Thanks

Comment: @VDWWD I have tried using `data-wrap="true"` which I found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp), but that doesn't work for my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what was wrong.

I looked through the Bootstrap documentation and noticed I was missing this tag outside the repeater:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
```

This solution below, works as expected:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="Rgallary" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="item <%# (Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "") %>">
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgId" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Company_Logo_Path", "~/Company_Logo/{0}") %>' />
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        Local Companies
                    </div>
                </div>
```